# Where and how should I use Composer and the drupal-composer/drupal-project scaffold to install the required libraries?

Tags: installation, theming, composer

I installed Drupal 8 using the drupal-composer/drupal-project scaffold. I also installed the Devel module, and enabled its Webprofiler submodule.

Drupal status reports that Webprofiler needs:

- D3.js library
- highlight.js library

There's no libraries path in my Drupal installation.

As I'm using composer, both D3 and highlight have packages.

- https://packagist.org/packages/mbostock/d3
- https://packagist.org/packages/components/highlightjs

That's a preferred option.

Where do the libraries need to actually go when using this scaffold?  What path?

How do I correctly use Composer on this install to put them there?

Although [Where should I download libraries for modules through composer?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183915/where-should-i-download-libraries-for-modules-through-composer) talks about it, it's only for the case of Composer Manager, which I am NOT using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/issues/68

clarifies the how-to install in custom locations, and NOT get redundant deps part of this question.

not yet, though, how to make Drupal -- particularly 'status' -- happy about it.

Answer (score 2):

I use https://github.com/oomphinc/composer-installers-extender in my projects. It provides an composer installer for any package type.

Comment: That looks like it should do the trick, thx.  Reading docs from the ComposerManager, "The Drupal 8 version of this module is deprecated and no longer needed, due to improvements in Drupal 8.1. Use Composer directly to get the needed modules, which will also download their required libraries." ... shouldn't the install of 'devel' module, then, already install the "required libraries"?

Comment: I set this up as instructed, and DO end up with D3 & Highlight under web/libraries.  But the 'require' also installs redundant copies of all the deps there too.  E.g., 'zippy' ends up being new-installed in ./web/libraries/zippy in addition to eh already-installed copy in ./vendor/alchemy/zippy/.  I suppose this has to do with the scaffold's organization.  So what's the correct path to use? to NOT get redundant copies of everything?

Comment: @ "Allow additional external libraries with composer" (https://www.drupal.org/node/1920666#comment-8538471) asks the question: "Are we still downloading duplicate library code if the module has a dependency on a packaged included in core?".  Afaict, there's no answer ?